What is the expected time this will take?
There are n white balls and m black balls in a bag. Select 2 balls randomly, if they're the same color, repaint both balls white, else repaint both balls black, then replace both balls in the bag. Keep on doing this once per minute until all balls in the bag are the same colour.
What is the expected time this will take?

one minute : you pick 2 balls, and then paint ALL balls black or white. so ALL balls are the same color. Maybe edit the question to make it clear which balls are painted :)

Related (though with different parameters): https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16049/31839

Unless there is a clever way to reformulate the problem that provides a shortcut to a simple calculation, this looks like a math problem to me, not a puzzle.

@FlorianF I'm voting to reopen. Based on the fact that so far it seems nobody's been able to solve this beyond partial answers, then it's probably not just a straightforward maths problem.

It seems unlikely that there is a puzzly solution here, unless the author can assert that one exists. The recursive approach for n balls seems like the most effective one, and it's not tractable by hand. Seems like this is a math problem, just a messy one.

@kagami I agree that it is a math problem, but not a messy one. For a given number n of balls essentially you have to invert an easy to derive (n-1)x(n-1) matrix and add the entries of each matrix row, see my approach below. But inverting a matrix is nothing what I would call in interesting solution for this puzzle. And I suspect that the author also does not have a more interesting solution.

Is an easy answer possible?
Eventually, if there is some hidden pattern in the solutions which allows a shortcut. To eventually find this we need the exact expected times and not some rounded values. The exact values can be computed with three lines of Mathematica code, so from a mathematical point of view the problem is an easy one.

 p[i_,j_,n_]:= 1/(n(n-1)) If [j==i,i(i-1),If[j==i-1,2i(n-i),If[j==i+2,(n-i)(n-i-1),0]]]
q[n_] := Table[p[i, j, n], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, n - 1}]
Table[{n,Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n-1]-q[n]].ConstantArray[1,n-1]},{n,3,10}]

The output gives for total number n of balls from 3 to 10 the expected times for 1,...n-1 white balls.

 {3, {1, 5/2}}
{4, {13/3, 14/3, 20/3}}
{5, {90/13, 2305/234, 385/39, 965/78}}
{6, {755/52, 463/26, 2109/104, 256/13, 295/13}}
{7, {203/8, 511/16, 273/8, 182/5, 35, 77/2}}
{8, {5033/110, 82228/1485, 3282/55, 306/5, 6269/99, 2000/33, 2132/33}}
{9, {2940212/37155, 49373941/520170, 8709171/86695, 2569343/24770, 259352/2477, 3699063/34678, 252549/2477, 527391/4954}}
{10, {28513897/209104, 2099793/13069, 141523965/836416, 645805/3734, 73434429/418208, 18396155/104552, 21232333/119488, 1268729/7468, 1306069/7468}}

The fractions get ugly for increasing n so I assume that there is no reasonably easy pencil and paper solution for an arbitrary large number of balls. The question seems to be a pure math problem.

Extremely partial answer:
Define f(n,m) as the expected number of moves until all balls are the same color. Therefore we get the following two equations due to basic probability -

f(0,m) = f(n,0) = 0 for all positive integers m,n
f(n,m) = (n/(n+m))((n-1)/(n+m-1))f(n,m) + 2(m/(n+m))(n/(n+m-1))f(n-1,m+1) + (m/(n+m))((m-1)/(n+m-1))f(n+2,m-2) + 1

This can be rearranged to make -

f(n,m) = (2n/(2n+m-1))f(n-1,m+1) + ((m-1)/(2n+m-1))f(n+2,m-2) + (n^2-n)/(m^2+2mn-m) + 1

This is a really ugly recursion to work with though, but I don't see a straightforward rearrangement to make it nicer to work with. If anyone sees a good way forward that would be helpful.

Welcome to PSE. The recursion is tricky indeed as it recurses onto itself as you might notice when you program it. So it does not always give answers. Maybe a lazy evaluation programming technique can avoid this. I assume however OP asks for an explicit non recursive formula.

Analysis
Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
W = & \text{ number of white balls}\\
B = & \text{ number of black balls}\\
N = & \text{ }W + B\\
\end{aligned} 
$$
At each step, there are three possibile events:
$$
\begin{aligned}
D_{WW} = & \text{ draw two white } & \rightarrow & \text{ no action}\\
D_{BB} = & \text{ draw two black } & \rightarrow & \text{ paint both white}\\
D_{WB} = & \text{ draw one of each } & \rightarrow & \text{ paint the white one black }\\
\end{aligned} 
$$
We can calculate the probabilities of these events at each step:
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(D_{WW}) = & \frac{W(W-1)}{N(N-1)} &
P(D_{BB}) = & \frac{B(B-1)}{N(N-1)} &
P(D_{WB}) = & \frac{2WB}{N(N-1)} \\
\end{aligned} 
$$
Let's fix $N$ and define
$$
T_W = \text{remaining time, given that there are currently } W \text{ white balls}
$$
Then the expected time until all balls are the same color is
$$
E[T_W] = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } W \in \{0, N\} \\
1 + E[T_W] * P(D_{WW}) + E[T_{W+2}] * P(D_{BB}) + E[T_{W-1}] * P(D_{WB}) & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
This is a recursive definition, but it can be solved.
Results
Here are results for $N = 2, 3, ...$
For some $W, B$ combinations, I list the probability for how $W$ will change.
For example P(+2)$ = P(\text{net gain of two white balls}) = P(D_{BB})$.
Then $\text{expected time}$ lists $E[T_0], E[T_1], ..., E[T_N]$
For example, with $1$ white and $3$ black balls, 4.333 minutes are expected for the balls to become the same color.
N = 2
W = 1, B = 1: P(+0)=0.0000  P(+2)=0.0000  P(-1)=1.0000  
Expected time = {0,1,0}

N = 3
W = 1, B = 2: P(+0)=0.0000  P(+2)=0.3333  P(-1)=0.6667  
W = 2, B = 1: P(+0)=0.3333  P(+2)=0.0000  P(-1)=0.6667  
Expected time = {0,1,2.5,0}

N = 4
W = 1, B = 3: P(+0)=0.0000  P(+2)=0.5000  P(-1)=0.5000  
W = 2, B = 2: P(+0)=0.1667  P(+2)=0.1667  P(-1)=0.6667  
W = 3, B = 1: P(+0)=0.5000  P(+2)=0.0000  P(-1)=0.5000  
Expected time = {0,4.33333,4.66667,6.66667,0}

N = 5
W = 1, B = 4: P(+0)=0.0000  P(+2)=0.6000  P(-1)=0.4000  
W = 2, B = 3: P(+0)=0.1000  P(+2)=0.3000  P(-1)=0.6000  
W = 3, B = 2: P(+0)=0.3000  P(+2)=0.1000  P(-1)=0.6000  
W = 4, B = 1: P(+0)=0.6000  P(+2)=0.0000  P(-1)=0.4000  
Expected time = {0,6.92308,9.85043,9.87179,12.3718,0}

N = 6
W = 1, B = 5: P(+0)=0.0000  P(+2)=0.6667  P(-1)=0.3333  
W = 2, B = 4: P(+0)=0.0667  P(+2)=0.4000  P(-1)=0.5333  
W = 3, B = 3: P(+0)=0.2000  P(+2)=0.2000  P(-1)=0.6000  
W = 4, B = 2: P(+0)=0.4000  P(+2)=0.0667  P(-1)=0.5333  
W = 5, B = 1: P(+0)=0.6667  P(+2)=0.0000  P(-1)=0.3333  
Expected time = {0,14.5192,17.8077,20.2788,19.6923,22.6923,0}

N = 7 Expected time = {0,25.375,31.9375,34.125,36.4,35,38.5,0}
N = 8 Expected time = {0,45.7545,55.3724,59.6727,61.2,63.3232,60.6061,64.6061,0}
N = 9 Expected time = {0,79.1337,94.9189,100.458,103.728,104.704,106.669,101.958,106.458,0}
N = 10 Expected time = {0,136.362,160.67,169.203,172.953,175.593,175.952,177.694,169.889,174.889,0}
N = 11 Expected time = {0,231.705,269.978,281.972,287.586,290.29,292.452,292.03,293.44,280.891,286.391,0}
N = 12 Expected time = {0,391.308,450.738,468.369,475.685,479.759,481.688,483.407,481.918,482.824,462.975,468.975,0}
N = 13 Expected time = {0,656.272,748.984,774.412,784.651,789.63,792.724,793.958,795.197,792.211,792.355,761.297,767.797,0}
N = 14 Expected time = {0,1095.34,1239.56,1276.73,1290.62,1297.38,1300.94,1303.3,1303.81,1304.47,1299.35,1298.35,1250.06,1257.06,0}
N = 15 Expected time = {0,1819.95,2044.55,2098.79,2118.07,2126.78,2131.58,2134.14,2135.85,2135.51,2135.43,2127.25,2124.56,2049.76,2057.26,0}
N = 16 Expected time = {0,3012.53,3362.14,3441.75,3468.39,3480.01,3485.95,3489.46,3491.19,3492.27,3490.86,3489.8,3477.2,3472.01,3356.42,3364.42,0}
N = 17 Expected time = {0,4969.25,5513.63,5630.69,5667.87,5683.22,5690.91,5695.12,5697.67,5698.63,5699.02,5696.22,5693.84,5674.84,5665.95,5487.56,5496.06,0}
N = 18 Expected time = {0,8170.86,9018.38,9191.09,9243.11,9263.65,9273.44,9278.81,9281.79,9283.55,9283.69,9283.27,9278.62,9274.42,9246.14,9231.8,8956.68,8965.68,0}
N = 19 Expected time = {0,13394.6,14714,14969.3,15042.5,15070.1,15082.7,15089.4,15093.2,15095.2,15096.2,15095.5,15094,15086.9,15080.2,15038.4,15016,14591.9,14601.4,0}
N = 20 Expected time = {0,21894.6,23947.7,24326.2,24429.6,24466.7,24483.1,24491.5,24496.1,24498.8,24500,24500.2,24498.4,24495.7,24485.1,24474.9,24413.4,24379.2,23725.5,23735.5,0}


Just for exactness in formula finding: the exact values of the set for N = 5 is {0,90/13,2305/234,385/39,965/78,0}.

I’m not giving an exact answer but a thinking process:

  Consider an especially simple case, let n+m=5. 


  step 1. it can easily be concluded that (like the diagram shows), under the repainting process, we can let these different states ⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️ ⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️⚪️, ⚫️⚫️⚪️⚪️⚪️,……⚫️⚫️⚫️⚫️⚫️ transit to each other.


  


 and, step 2. using the knowledge of combination theory, we can calculate the probabilities of each transition process:

 Now, step 3. we can label these six states with numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 (as the above picture shows), and, we can put those probability values into a transition matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}P_{11} & P_{12} & P_{13} & P_{14} & P_{15} & P_{16} \\ P_{21} & P_{22} & P_{23} & P_{24} & P_{25} & P_{26} \\ P_{31} & P_{32} & P_{33} & P_{34} & P_{35} & P_{36} \\ P_{41} & P_{42} & P_{43} & P_{44} & P_{45} & P_{46} \\P_{51} & P_{52} & P_{53} & P_{54} & P_{55} & P_{56} \\ P_{61} & P_{62} & P_{63} & P_{64} & P_{65} & P_{66} \\ \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\0& 0.3 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0.1 \\0.3 & 0 & 0.1& 0.6 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 &0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$
 where $P_{ij}$ means transiting from the i-th state to the j-th state. Now, the iteration process is can be mathematically expressed as the process of matrix multiplication consecutively. 
 step4. I calculated the first three iterations using the wolfram alpha (not bringing my computer with me, so I just use the screenshot pictures instead of LaTeX equations) 



Minor nitpick but you have an error in your diagram: state 3 should be 2 white 3 black not 1 white 4 black.

@BlazingSnow Thank you for pointing out this mistake! I will update it.

I’m not sure if the ‘thought process’ is OK as an answer on this site, and,  if not,  I will delete it later.
